# Excel VBA - Assigning range to variant using .cells property error,

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells, variant

I've the following code extract below,

```
Dim profileRange as Variant

profileRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scenario").Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(5, "C"))
```

Then I get the following in the watch expression

```
Watch Expression: profileRange
Value: Empty
Type: Variant/Empty
```

It's supposed to get the numbers assigned in that sheet..which goes form 1 to 5

Also, I get this when running the code

```
Error 1004:
Application or Object defined error
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
profileRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scenario").Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(5, "C"))
```

to this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scenario")
    profileRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(5, "C"))
End with
```

Cells() are range object and need to have parentage assigned.  Without dictating parentage it is  trying to use the active sheet, so the range parentage does not equate to the cells parentage.

By using the With block with the `.` allows consistent parentage throughout.

Comment: Hey Scott, how do I assign this to the profileRange?

Comment: @lukieleetronic sorry forgot the array.  I fixed it.  Please consider marking as correct.